# Which SkypeKit SDK i should download to actually build android application

Tags: android

I want to develop a Skype app in android. for doing the same we need download the SkypeKit SDK. There are 2 SDKs avaliable. Skypekit SDK for embedded devices and Skypekit SDK for Desktop apps. Which one should i download? I downloaded the Skypekit SDK for embedded devices. But when i check the refernece directory i am not finding any relevant data there to use in android app.
So please tell me which one to download.

Comment: hey can you provide me the SkypeKit SDK you have downloaded ? because i'm not able to download it right now from the skype site it says "The Skype Developer program is not accepting new registrations".

Answer (score 0):

You should download Skypekit SDK for embedded devices. As android is built on Linux check in Linux folder for relevant files. You will have no seperate folder for android but you can use all the resources from Linux folder.